# Alternation priority?

Tags: regex

Givin the following text:

```
constraint FK1 foreign key (Store_id) references "Store",
constraint FK2 foreign key (Product_id) references "Product"),
CONSTRAINT PK1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT FK3 FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES user(id)
```

I am trying to figure out a regular expression that gives me the local column (Store_id, Product_id and id_user) the table (Store, Product and User) and the target tables column (if applicable id in FK3).

If I use the following regex:

```
FOREIGN\s+KEY\s+?\(([^(]+)\)\s+?REFERENCES\s+(\"[^\"]+\")
```

It properly matches the first two options.

If I use this regex:

```
FOREIGN\s+KEY\s+?\(([^(]+)\)\s+?REFERENCES\s+([^(]+)\(([^)]+)
```

It properly matches FK3 but not FK1 or FK2. I was hoping I could combine this with an `alteration`. I tried the following:

```
FOREIGN\s+KEY\s+?\(([^(]+)\)\s+?REFERENCES\s+((\"[^\"]+\")|[^(]+)\(([^)]+)
```

Assuming that because I put state 1 first that would provide a valid match for the first two options, however instead it performs as the second regex.

Any suggestions on how I can do this properly? Is there a way to set a priority on an Alternation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down your alternation, here's what you get:

```
\s+(
    ("[^"]+")
    |
    [^(]+
)
\( ([^)]+)
```

Try this regex instead:

```
FOREIGN KEY \(([^)]+)\) REFERENCES ("[^"]+"|\([^)]+\))
```